# WCF linq to query from multiple table

Tags: sql, wpf, linq, wcf

i have two tables Employee and Permenent table.
permenet table is a ISA table of Employee
 here is the schema of two tables

```
create table employees(

employee_no varchar(5),
name varchar(50),
nic varchar(10),
address varchar(100),
designation varchar(20),

Land varchar(10),
Mobile varchar(10),  
constraint pkemployees primary key(employee_no),
constraint fkemployees foreign key(land,mobile) references telephone)


create table permenenet(

username varchar(20),
password varchar(10),
password_hint varchar(50),
employee_no varchar(5),
constraint fkpermenet foreign key(employee_no) references employees,
constraint pkpermenet primary key(employee_no).
```

i have created WCF service to get the name and designation

```
    public List<employee>get_name(string uname){
                 var resl = (from per in dc.permenenets
                 join emp in dc.employees on per.employee_no equals emp.employee_no
                 where  per.username == uname && per.employee_no == emp.employee_no 
                 select emp);
     return resl.ToList();
    }
```

but when i am testing with WCF client or getting data from WPF application i am getting empty answers.Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

1. The part `&& per.employee_no == emp.employee_no` is not necessary since you already have join on this condition.
2. Also you select only `permenenets` that have the `username` exactly equal to `uname` so it generates similar SQL to `per.username = @uname` but not `per.username LIKE @uname`. If you do not seek exact match then would have to use `SqlMethods.Like` or something else.
3. Check somehow value `resl.ToString()` (i.e. by setting breakpoint and using watch) and try to run the generated query directly against SQL Server and replace the parameter with `uname` value and see if you get any results.